# Converting gray scale image to 3 dimensional tensor (N, N, 1) with Pillow

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make YOLO architecture with an input of gray scaled image.
In general, input of YOLO is RGB image (3-dim tensor), whose size is (N, N, 3), where N is size of an image and 3 represents R,G and B channel.
When reading an image with pillow, the code below gives me 2-dim tensor image. Which is, (N , N).

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('sample.jpg')
image = image.convert('L')
```

However, in order to have this image as an input of YOLO architecture, I need the size of it to be (N, N, 1) , where 1 represents gray channel. Which is 3-dim tensor.

If possible, I would be glad if the solution was given in code using pillow.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in Pillow, there is no way to do what I want. So instead, I decided to use numpy.